# How to hide backend layout in folders

Tags: typo3, backend

In pages of type *folder* nobody want to add content. It's not meaningful and you get the warning "Go to list module" if you are in page module.

How can I disable the display of "Normal" (name of default column) and the button `[+ Content]`? It's not useful and confusing for editors.

I tried something with backend layouts but with no success.

Comment: There is a use case for having content in folders; shared content elements inserted onto other pages using references. So I wouldn't say "nobody wants to add content" :)

Comment: @Unnamed_1 that's right, of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wondering, what you have tried with backend layouts so far.

The following is working since versions (including v10):

```
mod.web_layout.BackendLayouts {
  exampleKey {
    title = Example
    icon = EXT:example_extension/Resources/Public/Images/BackendLayouts/default.gif
    config {
      backend_layout {
        colCount = 0
        rowCount = 0
        rows {
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it by the wizard. Now it works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Maybe, one of us should open a feature/change request for the wizard. 0-values should be valid.